# How do I combine these Array values?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hi I have the following Array structure, how can I merge the sub-array values by `['number']` ?

```
 array(4) { 
          ["success"]=> bool(true) 
          ["messages"]=> array(2)
           {  

            ["0"]=> array(5){

                ["number"]=>string(1)                           
                ["incoming_id"]=> string(6)                        
                ["usernumber"]=> string(13)                         
                ["content"]=> string(4)                           
                ["date"]=> string(10)  

                }

            ["1"]=> array(5){

                ["number"]=>string(1)                           
                ["incoming_id"]=> string(6)                        
                ["usernumber"]=> string(13)                         
                ["content"]=> string(4)                           
                ["date"]=> string(10)  

                }  
        }             
       ["start"]=> string(1) 
       ["next"]=> string(2) 
       }
```

I want the following thing: If the value of `['number']` in `[0]` is the same as in `[1]` they should be saved in one new Array. For Example `[0]['number']-> 1234` and `[1]['number'] -> 1234` their values should be merged into one array named `[1234]->` content from `[0]['content']` , content from `[1]['content'].`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please edit the question by correctly formating the `[0][Number...` part as to me it is unclear what you want and this reads also invalid php. Thanks.

Comment: @Dilettant   -  Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I guess so, as an answer has been offered. Does it fit? Then you might accept it;-) thanks for the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to traverse the array and group all these values together:

```
$grouped = array();
foreach ($array as $data) {
    if (!isset($grouped[$data['number']])) {
        $grouped[$data['number']] = array();
    }

    $grouped[$data['number']][] = $data;
}
```

Or you can use [indexed](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl#indexedsequence-by-keeplast--true-transform--null) function from [NSPL](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl).

```
use function \nspl\a\indexed;

$grouped = indexed($array, 'number', false);
```